# How to check one multi-dimensional array values against another multi-array and update bulk data depending on results, using PHP and MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I've a table that has three columns id, points, rank. Timely I update data for all fields so points go up and down but old rankings remains same, so I'm trying to find out a way that entitles each id its deserving rank based on points earned.

I've got more than 2000 rows in this table. I wish to do it in php5+ with mysqli? I think I've a solution but it times out even with 1200 seconds timeout setting and memory gets exhausted.

I think my solution works accurately but any of the loops needs some doctor. Here my rough target is 'update' query to go accurate that takes all points in desc order, and awards id a rank against the points earned:

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/db.inc.php';


$a2= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM p1");
$b2 =mysqli_fetch_array($a2);
$count = $b2['count'];

$i=1;
while($i<=$count){
$a1= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT points FROM p1 ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT     $i");
if(!$a1){
echo mysqli_error($link);
}
while($po = mysqli_fetch_array($a1)){

$ross[] = $po; 
}   
foreach($ross as $pot){
$points=$pot['points'];
}  

$a5a= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM p1 WHERE points = '$points'");

while($popo = mysqli_fetch_array($a5a)){

$idi=$popo;
}  
foreach($idi as $idm){
$id=$idm['id'];

$rank = $i;
$update = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE p1 SET rank = '$rank' WHERE points = '$points' AND id ='$id'");
}    
if(!$update){
echo "Error updating Rank".mysqli_error($link);
}  else {
echo "Succuessul for where id = '$id' and points = '$points' set rank = '$rank'<br/>";
}      
$i++;   
}  
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please fix indentation of your code.

Comment: fixed the indent. I guess! Now help me geeks!

Comment: frankly with aproach and comments like this you may not recieve any answers here.

Comment: I hope you prove to be wrong LOL, but yeah! I totally agree with you, so could you just point it out where should I head to or look into? any idea Mate! Thanx 4 suggestion, and sorry but your answer failed. sorry don't wanna bother anyone at all. the problem is kinda big for me as I am newly born  baby to coding with no parents at all.

Comment: @Zmrzka : You almost hit the bulls eye! I copied and ran through your code it failed to do anything but yeah! your code gave me the right method to sort it out. I've fixed the bug.  the $rank++; idea is far more better  than running those excess loops. I removed the distinct too. just looped through all the points and ids with foreach and gave the update command within foreach. and just before foreach $rank=0; and just before update $rank++; and my echo tells exactly what the code is doing. it's damn swift too. I mean the code. thanks for ur effort mate! Taa!

Comment: well I had to grab my old code (build for something else )  and copy paste mix it with yours wihout executing it so there might be slight errors. its good idea to tell more than just "it do not work" but what whats wrong? error messages? did new table build correctly? again its hard to response wihout specific inforamtion

Comment: @zmrzka honestly I copied pasted your suggestion and made necessary changes and ran it. I didn't receive any echo messages as you didn't command it to do so anywhere in the code, neither there were any php scripting errors nor I was able to find any changes to my table.

Comment: Well you can add relevant echo or var_dump() point is that my approach is designed to make just the difference when its needed while you code issues updates allways... lets imagine that you table grows to half a milion. Now you will issue half a milion updates to your DB to change 20 ranks? Think its a good idea?

Comment: There is actualy eaven better and faster approach I will adapt my answer accordingly

Comment: @zmrzka true. but even after having fixed errors on ur code it says:

Comment: @zmrzka true. but even after having fixed errors on ur code it says: <br/>"Warning: Illegal string offset 'points' in C:\wamp64\www\mysite\command.php on line 17"  "<br/>"pls build a small table on ur server insert few line with a couple or more with same numbers as points and try to compile and fix errors if occurs. pls "<br/>" I really believe ur idea as a Perfect One. u're awesome man. not buttering.

Comment: posted updated code but sorry I am not going to construct and debug complete code, DB tables and hand you complete and functioning code to you. Just try it yourself else you are not gonna learn anything :)

Comment: just elaborate what exactly line 17 has, $table_new[$line["id"]]["rank"] = $ranks[$line["points"]]; it's an error here: illegal offset rank.?

Comment: in this line you add new rank into the second dimension of $table_new, strange thing is that I executed this code and it worked perfectly. there may be differences since I possibly have different php.ini, different OS and different version of PHP. this would be for another question I gues, only thing I can say is that old code works on my machine :)

Comment: don't need to think about those lines anymore as I hardly understand php that way and why should we waste time for what we already have got our answer. One more thing adding select all three columns for comparing and neglecting db for more of update commands  does the trick but as it's said simplicity and shortness of code is premium. so you're the premium GURU. you owe me boss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have replaced my original answer with much leaner and shorter code, you can of course include modification to the rank counter if consecutive users have same points but you can figure this yourself

This code have just one loop and is conserving memory and your DB as well

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/db.inc.php';
$a = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, points, rank FROM p1 ORDER BY points DESC ");    // lets get users in new ordering
$rank = 1;                                  // new ranks
while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($a)){
  if ($rank != $line["rank"]) {          //if old rank is different  we will hit db with new value
    echo "updating id ".$line["id"]." from rank ".$line["rank"]." to rank ".$rank." <br>";
    if(!mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE p1 SET rank = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$rank)."' WHERE id ='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$line["id"])."'")) {
      echo "Error updating Rank".mysqli_error($link);
    }
  }else {  //if its the same we just leave the message for now
    echo "ignoring id ".$line["id"]." previous rank ".$line["rank"]." , new rank ".$rank." <br>";
  }
  $rank++;    // next user so lets increment the counter
}
?>
```

Comment: Yo! Man. Glad to have some angel like you. It's cool and efficient. I must say Perfect. thanks again You're my GURU Now.

Answer (score 0):

Recently went through same kind of issue and found a simple solution like below after struggling a lot. I would like to clear it out that, it depends on your input and expected result as well which you didn't mention in your post.

```
if (preg_match('/"'.<value>.'"/i' , json_encode(<your array>))) {
    echo "Match";
} else {
    echo "Doesn't match";
}
```

Please replace values accordingly when trying! Thanks for reading it.

Comment: my target is if($id==$max['points']){ then rank =1, where id='$id' that is the id we matched just now then who has second max points gets 2 rank and so on. if you think you know the answer then please edit my code accordingly and send it back please.

Comment: Did you try - preg_match('/"'.$id.'"/i' , json_encode($max['points']))) ?

Comment: Sorry! Just don't wanna annoy you but really don't know where exactly to change my code. there are three arrays one has ranks, another has id and last one has points id's are not necessary to use but I wanna assign max to min points rankings 1 ++; maybe I'm unable to convey my question   clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer code takes all points, and relevant ids and sets high to low ranks against high to low points respectively. However, it does not assign same rank for same points holder id as it keeps rolling with Rank+1 until end. That could be done, but isn't presently required.

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/db.inc.php';    //connection to the DB 
$a1= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, points FROM p1 ORDER BY points DESC"); //Selecting High to low all points 
if(!$a1){
echo mysqli_error($link);
}
while($po = mysqli_fetch_array($a1)) {                                                                                                                                            

$rose[] = $po;

}

$rank=0;//set rank 0

foreach($rose as $ro) { //splitting each row of array with unlimited rows

$points=$ro['points'];
$id=$ro['id'];

$rank++; //adding 1 each time foreach loops repeats itself until no row left
$update = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE player1 SET rank = '$rank' WHERE points = '$points' AND id ='$id'"); //sending update command

if(!$update) { //echoing out what the hell this code is f******
echo "Error updating Rank".mysqli_error($link);
}  else {
echo "Succuessul for where id = '$id' and points = '$points' set rank = '$rank'<br/>";
} 
} 
?>
```